# Error when accessing FBResult after FB.API call in a coroutine

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

When accessing the Text (and Error) properties of an FBResult after an FB.API call in a coroutine there's a NullReferenceException because the internal WWW object has already been disposed.

```
    FBResult result = null;

    FB.API(query,httpMethod,(r)=>{
        result = r;
    });

    while(result==null) yield return null;

    print(result.Text);//Accessing result.Text produces error.
```

NullReferenceException: WWW class has already been disposed.

UnityEngine.WWW.get_text ()

FBResult.get_Text ()

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/DelegateTypes) clearly states

> Note that FBResult implements IDisposable, meaning that FBResult
>   objects are subject to deallocation after the callback is called. If
>   you want to save a texture, or the string, save those values rather
>   than trying to save the FBResult itself.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the result inside the callback, since that is the whole point of having a callback.

```
FBResult result = null;

FB.API(query,httpMethod,(r)=>{
    result = r;
    print(result.Text);
});
```

Waiting outside in the way you are doing is not the correct way to do that.

Comment: Surely the point of the callback is to let me know when the operation is done. Why can't I keep a reference to result and use elsewhere?

Comment: Because after the callback method is finished (in this case, everything that is inside the { )}, the values gets disposed.

You make result = r, but after the callback is finished, r gets disposed, and now result is pointing to a disposed variable, hence the message you are receiving

Comment: Why is it disposed if I have a second reference to it? Isn't that what reference counting is for?

Comment: Actually I use similar code for my login with no such issue.